# Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<T,TKey>'

Tags: c#, generics

I'm writing a generic class for min heap where I want to be able to heapify on `TKey` as well as `T`.

```
interface IHeap<T, TKey>
    where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    void Insert(T x);
    T Delete();
    T Top();
}

public class MinHeap<T, TKey> : IHeap<T, TKey>
    where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    public MinHeap(int capacity)
        : this(capacity, x => x) // <---- compilation error here
    { }
    public MinHeap(int capacity, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
        : this(capacity, keySelector, Comparer<TKey>.Default)
    { }
    public MinHeap(int capacity, Func<T, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

I get these compilation errors for `x => x`:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<T,TKey>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.
Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'TKey'
```

How do I achieve this and just have one class?

Update:

I want to be able to do two things:

```
// 1
var minheap = new MinHeap<Person, int>(10, x => x.Age);

// 2
var minheap = new MinHeap<int>(10);
// instead of 
var minheap = new MinHeap<int, int>(10, x => x);
```

Comment: The compiler error is clear about why the code is invalid. Your question is _not_ clear regarding why you think such code should work. The point of generics is to provide compile-time type safety, but given your current declarations, it's not possible to ensure type safety at compile time for that expression. Please explain your thinking better.

Comment: I'd like to heapify Person[] on Person.Age, a person's property (`TKey`). I'd also like to heapify on int[] (`T`).

Comment: Wanting to do something isn't an explanation. I'd like my C# compiler to hand me a chocolate mint every time I compile my program, but there's not really any point in me asking how I can get it to do that. It's understood that that's just not possible. Likewise, you're asking the compiler to do something that is plainly impossible. Please explain _why_ you think it should be possible. Ben's answer comes the closest to something I think would be useful in this context, but I fear it doesn't truly address your misunderstanding. We can't do that without understand that misunderstanding better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MinHeap<T,TKey>` can be instantiated with any generic type parameters matching the constraints.

That means for example, you could have a `MinHeap<string,int>`. In that case, you'd be trying to assign lambda `x => x` to a `Func<string,int>` which wouldn't work, since it's a `Func<string,string>`.

I don't think there is a sensible way to achieve what you want, as there's no good candidate for a "default" way to convert one arbitrary type to another arbitrary type, which is what you'd need.

---

What you could do is remove this constructor and add a static constructor which could be used for the cases when the `T` and `TKey` are the same type:

```
public static class MinHeap
{
    public static MinHeap<T,T> Create<T>(int capacity) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return new MinHeap<T,T>(capacity, x => x);
    }
}
```

But if this isn't enough for your needs, then just remove the constructor and accept that people will have to deal with passing a lambda in themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the example and a workaround. I chose to pass the lambda rather than a static helper method.

Answer (score 2):

`x => x` is a `Func<T, T>`, not a `Func<T, TKey>` as required in your other constructor.

You need to have a default selector, or better yet I would disallow that constructor and force the user to provide a key selector when instantiating the class.

Answer (score -1):

I'm adding my answer as

1. Few people did not understand what I wanted to do despite giving
   an example.
2. No one mentioned this answer.

I removed the constructor from `MinHeap<T, TKey>`. I defined another class as below.

```
public class MinHeap<T> : MinHeap<T, T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public MinHeap(int capacity)
        : this(capacity, Comparer<T>.Default)
    { }
    public MinHeap(int capacity, IComparer<T> comparer)
        : base(capacity, x => x, comparer)
    { }
}
```

Comment: why -1? please explain.